# Finding extrema of function of two unit vectors

Tags: optimization, vectors

I have a simple function of the form
$$
f(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}},\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}) = \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\cdot\boldsymbol{a} + \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}\cdot\boldsymbol{b} + \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol{y}}c
$$
of two unit vectors and I want to find the extrema of this function, but am somehow stuck, by the fact that these are unit vectors.

Is there an elegant vector-based solution? Or do I have to express each unit vector by spherical polar coordinates ...? Perhaps one can construct a function $\tilde{f}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})$ whose extrema occur for $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ being unity and coincide with those of $f(\hat{\boldsymbol{x}},\hat{\boldsymbol{y}})$.

Comment: You could start by noting that $\bf{\hat{x}\cdot a}$ is the projection of $\bf{a}$ on $\bf{\hat{x}}$, i.e. is simply the $x$-component of $\bf{a}$...

Comment: @Demosthene $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}$ is one of the function arguments and not a constant unit vector.

Comment: Still, $\bf{\hat{x}\cdot{a}}$ is the projection of $\bf{a}$ on $\bf{\hat{x}}$, therefore the component of $\bf{a}$ in the $\bf{\hat{x}}$-direction, whatever that direction actually is.

Comment: @Demosthene yes, of course. so what?